# Get hour data from date column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I select data between two date with hours. My oracle column date's format is:`10.04.2006 19:10:37` I can select between twou days with:

```
select date from table where date between '1/1/2011' and '2/1/2011
```

but I will select between hours which hours are in date column i.e:

`select date from table where date between '1/1/2011 22:00'and '2/1/2011 21:00'` what can I do

Comment: `10/04` can be April 10th or October 4th

Comment: sorry I bought your time thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `to_date` to specify a [custom date format](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php):

```
where    date between to_date('1/1/2011 22:00', 'DD/MM/yyyy HH24:MI')
                      and to_date('2/1/2011 21:00', 'DD/MM/yyyy HH24:MI')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I usually do.

```
where date between date'2011-1-1'+22/24 and date'2011-1-2'+21/24
```

On the column

```
TRUNC(date_col)+hours/24
```

Comment: Floating point math is not exact, which makes it less than ideal for limiting date ranges

Comment: @Andomar I never look out for it.. Could you tell the details or give me an example? Thanks

Comment: I'd expect `'2011-1-2'+21/24` to result in a time that is slightly different from `21:00` but can't find way to reproduce it.  SQL Fiddle doesn't support the `to_char(sysdate, 'HH23:MI:SS.FF9')`.

Comment: I've never come across a problem like that, possibly because Oracle doesn't use IEEE math, so it's not as susceptible to floating point problems. sysdate is a DATE of course, so you cannot extract fractions of a second from it, and the smallest numeric increment required is 1/(24*60*60) = 0.000011574074 according to sqlfiddle, or 0.000011574 according to my Ubuntu calculator.

Comment: @DavidAldridge  Thanks for your explaination,and I tried this sql SELECT CASE WHEN TO_DATE('2011-1-1 22:33:04','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')=DATE'2011-1-1'+22/24+33/24/60+4/24/60/60 THEN 1
ELSE 0 END FROM DUAL; It returns 1.So I think I don't need to modify the procedures I developed before... lol